# Using image after loading on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have loaded a remote image from Facebook on to my webpage. I am wanting to find where it is cached so I can get the src path to it so I can use it on my canvas. The problem I am having is when I try to set the Facebook src path it is giving me cross origin errors because it is not a local file. Is this something that HTML5 local storage might solve?

In the end I would like to have a path to the loaded image that does not involve me saving them to my server and pulling them down again.

Comment: You should probably use a data URL. Send the image to your server, have it convert it to a data URL, and then use that.

Comment: Are you trying to access the image from an iframe? Are you trying to get access to the pixels once loaded into the canvas? These are both restricted on cross-origin resources.

Comment: I am getting the images from the Facebook sdk so it gives me an actual image link. My thought process is that the image has to be 'saved' locally somewhere that I could reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by adding the image by jquery on the `.load()` because The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded,

Comment: Does this give me a path to image or is it the image saved in the variable I called load with?